# jump to 2nd form and hide first form then close 2nd and show first form

Tags: c#, forms

I want to jump to 2nd form from first form in c# when I open 2nd and close main form by using below code all forms are close while jumping to 3rd by 2nd and do same then only 2nd form close and 3rd still on screen.

```
       {
        frmLogin login = new frmLogin();
            login.Show();
            this.Close();

    }
```

how I able to close main form without closing all other forms???
(Note: I am new so any mistake i made please ignore it.)

Comment: Your problem description is gibberish to me, it's extremely difficult to discern what the problem is and what you're trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: when i do this.close() on main form it close itself and all other forms also closed.

Comment: Maybe you want `this.hide()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void OpenMainForm()
{
    var login = new frmLogin();
    this.Hide();          
    login.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();          
}
```